# Redirect is not working on Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-4, require

In my controller function I am using a `require` statement to include a file:

```
require app_path().'/plivo/plivo.php';
```

After this statement, I try to redirect from this controller using the following statement:

```
return Redirect::back()->with('success', 'Note added successfully');
```

However, this gives me the following error:

> Call to undefined method `Redirect::back()`

How can I redirect from this function?

This is my full code:

```
public function sendSMS(){
    require app_path().'/plivo/plivo.php';
    $auth_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
    $auth_token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    $p = new \RestAPI($auth_id, $auth_token);

    $params = array(
        'src' => '1XX7XX0',
        'dst' => '91XXXXXXXXX7',
        'text' => 'Test SMS',
        'method' => 'POST'
    );
    $response = $p->send_message($params);
    return Redirect::back()->with('success', 'Note added successfully');
}
```

Comment: Is your code namespaced? Try `return \Redirect::back()...`?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange I tried this also. not working

Comment: Hi @Vinod VT your controller will look cleaner if you move plivo and its methods into a package. I can see that its an SMS gateway. https://www.plivo.com. I created a package for an SMS gateway I use which enables me to do something like this `Sms::send('080000000', 'message'); ` I really think you should do the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer assumes that `plivo.php` is from [this git repo](https://github.com/plivo/plivo-php).

The issue is that the `plivo.php` library defines a `Redirect` class in the global namespace. Because of this, Laravel does not register the global `Redirect` alias to point to the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect` facade.

So, in your final line `return Redirect::back()->with(...);`, the `Redirect` class being used is the class defined in the `plivo.php` library, not Laravel's `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect` class.

The quickest fix would be to change your line to:

```
return Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::back()->with('success', 'Note added successfully');
```

Another option would be to inject Laravel's redirector into your controller, and use that instead of using the facade:

```
class MyController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct(\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector $redirector) {
        $this->redirector = $redirector;
    }

    public function sendSMS() {
        require app_path().'/plivo/plivo.php';
        //
        return $this->redirector->back()->with('success', 'Note added successfully');
    }
}
```

A third option would be to update your code to use the plivo composer package, which has a namespace. The updates have been done in the `dev` branch of the repo, which you can find [here](https://github.com/plivo/plivo-php/tree/dev). If you did this, you would get rid of your `require` statement and use the namespaced plivo classes.